# What is the name of the first known word from which the current word is derived?

Tags: etymology, words

I'm interested in the name of the concept that defines the word from which another word comes.
For example, "Guild" comes from the German "Gilde". What is the name of the word "Gilde" in this case? Original, first or something else?
I tried to google, ask ChatGPT, but so far I haven’t found anything adequate. It seems to say that this is called “proto-form”, but this word refers to chemistry, as I understand it

Comment: I think I would just use: word origin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymology

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Proto-form* may also be used in chemistry, but in linguistics it refers to a *reconstructed* form from which other forms are derived (see [proto-language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-language) and [comparative method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative_method#Application)). An example of a proto-form is Proto-Indo-European [**g<sup>h</sup>eh<sub>1</sub>b<sup>h</sup>*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/g%CA%B0eh%E2%82%81b%CA%B0-) 'to grab, take', from which we get Latin *habēo*, *habitus* > English *habit*, but also Welsh [*gafael*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gafael#Welsh) 'to hold, grasp'. Like the "proto" in "proto-form", the "proto" in "Proto-Indo-European" indicates that this language is not actually attested in any sources but that it is reconstructed on the basis of evidence from languages that are related to each other.

In "**g<sup>h</sup>eh<sub>1</sub>b<sup>h</sup>*", the asterisk indicates that this is form is not actually attested but is a reconstructed proto-form. Not all proto-forms have lots of superscripts and subscripts; this depends on the complexity of the reconstructed phonology. The Hebrew and Arabic for 'son' can be reconstructed as Proto-Semitic [**bin-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Semitic/bin-), for example.

"Proto-form" may be what you are looking for, though it is not strictly speaking a "*known* word", since we do not have evidence for it. In the case of *habit* above, Latin *habēo* appears to be the first *attested* form from which English *habit* is derived.

In the case of *guild*, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guild#English) derives it from Old Norse [*gildi*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gildi#Old_Norse) rather than German *Gilde* (though the latter is of course related, and Wiktionary may be wrong, too). This is a nominal derivation of the verb [*gjalda*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gjalda#Old_Norse) 'to pay', which is reconstructed for Proto-Germanic as [*geldaną](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/geldan%C4%85). So here the first attested word from which *guild* is *derived* could be said to be *gjalda*, though you could also decide to exclude morphological derivations, in which case it would be *gildi*.

I am not aware of a specific term for this concept, but "first attested form" seems to work alright. You should be aware, however, that *guild* may not actually be derived from any of the attested forms of *gildi*. For example, *gildi* may have been loaned into English in the year X, while *gildi* only appears in Old Norse sources in X+50. In that case, *gildi* is the source for *guild*, but none of the actually attested instances of *gildi* are the source for *guild*. Does *gildi* still count as the "first attested form" of *guild*?

Comment: great minds! Your answer is certainly more complete than mine though!

Comment: @Tristan Definitely do keep it though, as you suggested many more terms!

Comment: English _have_ is not from derived from, or even related to, Latin _habeō_, despite the superficial similarity. The Latin cognate is _capiō_, both being from the root [_*kap-/*keh₂p-_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/kap-) ‘grasp’ (likely an onomatopoetic root, or possibly substrate). The earliest attested form of _have_ would be Old English [_habban_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/habban#Old_English).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet oh thanks! I looked at *habit* as the first word that came to mind for whatever reason, and then assumed *have* would have the same origin. I'll adapt the answer.

Answer (score 11):

I don't believe there is a single word. I would describe this as the "**earliest attested antecedent**". I might also use another word like "**predecessor**", "**etymon**", or "**form**" instead of "antecedent", depending on the specific example and relationship between it and the current word under consideration (in particular I would be less likely to use the word "form" if the word has been borrowed, as in this case). The key part here is "**earliest attested**".

Proto-form would imply to me that the term is a reconstruction. I would not use it for an attested word.